# python increment number in the URL

Tags: python, loops, increment

is there any possible way to have a increment of two different numbers in the URL that I have? One f the number will be starting with -1. Second number will be starting with 0.

```
url = "https://mywebsite.com/amp"
for count in range(-1, 5):
    print(url + str(count))
```

this gives me

```
https://mywebsite.com/amp-1
https://mywebsite.com/amp0
https://mywebsite.com/amp1
https://mywebsite.com/amp2
https://mywebsite.com/amp3
https://mywebsite.com/amp4
```

I'm trying to achieve this

```
https://mywebsite.com/amp=-1&id=0
https://mywebsite.com/amp=0&id=1
https://mywebsite.com/amp=1&id=2
https://mywebsite.com/amp=2&id=3
https://mywebsite.com/amp=3&id=4
```

Comment: `print(url + str(count) + '&id=' + str(count+1))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
url = "https://mywebsite.com/amp"
for count in range(-1, 5):
    print(f"{url}/amp={count}&id={count+1}")
```

Output:

```
https://mywebsite.com/amp/amp=-1&id=0
https://mywebsite.com/amp/amp=0&id=1
https://mywebsite.com/amp/amp=1&id=2
https://mywebsite.com/amp/amp=2&id=3
https://mywebsite.com/amp/amp=3&id=4
https://mywebsite.com/amp/amp=4&id=5
```

Do keep in mind that if you want the query string to pass values as proper parameters, you need to add a `?` after the first `/amp`. Like this:

```
https://mywebsite.com/amp?amp=-1&id=0
```

Comment: I think you should have `?amp=`, otherwise the `&` doesn't make sense as a query parameter

Comment: You are absolutely right @OneCricketeer. I just tried to stick to the output OP wanted though...

Comment: Isn't it better to use the [right tool for the job](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode)?

Answer (score 1):

Using `str.format()`:

```py
for n in range(-1, 4):
    print('{}?amp={}&id={}'.format(url, n, n+1))
```